# Xcode Interface Builder - reusing a UIView

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Is it not possible to reuse a UIView with constraints etc, from one view to another. I have tried:
Note: I am not in storyboard, but using xib file in a framework that I am creating - therefore I am using only UIView from xib files.

1. Tried to reference view in the same xib file.
2. @IBDesignable incl all custom classe setup.

I am only looking for reusing a UIView incl. constraints.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this through the storyboard because constraints are not made to be generalized through viewcontrollers. If you copy and paste constraints, they'll look for the exact views they used to constrain which won't be there anymore.

However if you have multiple views that look similar, then my suggestion would be to make a base class where you layout the view once on the storyboard and then subclass it. Or, your other option would be programmatic.